# Unable to route in ruby on rails as I encounter specific error

Tags: ruby

[image: img]

I'm using rails 5.0 and I get the

> `PostsController#index` is missing a template for this request format and variant. request.formats: ["text/html"] request.variant: []

NOTE! For XHR/Ajax or API requests while trying to input my url/posts.

my routing.rb file is below:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    get 'posts/index' => 'posts#index'
    resources: posts
end
```

my posts_controller.rb looks like below:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
    def index



    end
end
```

I want to know specifically what I'm doing wrong. I've just started to learning Ruby on Rails.

Comment: Your template (as I could see on the image provided) has a redundant `.txt` extension. Rename a template file to `index.html.erb`.

Comment: I'm so glad I'm getting answers for this question. But when i initially created a file in my view folder -> posts, I've created a new text file and renamed it as index.html.erb However, when I try to edit this file with notepad++ or view the properties of the file it indicates it as index.html.erb.txt as it was initially created as a text file.

Comment: If you want to continue with programming you probably should consider switching from `notepad++` to anything more robust, e.g. `atom`, `sublime`, `visual studio code` etc.

Comment: Ok, I'll do that, thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Template is missing. You need to create a file ie index.html.erb under directory /app/views/posts/index.html

Comment: I'm so glad I'm getting answers for this question. But when i initially created a file in my view folder -> posts, I've created a new text file and renamed it as index.html.erb However, when I try to edit this file with notepad++ or view the properties of the file it indicates it as index.html.erb.txt as it was initially created as a text file.

Comment: Thanks for all your help guys. I think I found a route to solve the issue. I've just changed the type of file using notepad++ and renamed the file. You've resurrected my thirst to learn ruby.. Many thanks..

Comment: @madannealcaffrey Vote my answer if i works for you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```html
GET profiles/employees- Should display all the employees
GET profiles/employees/:id should display a specfic employee
GET profiles/donors - Should display all the donors
GET profiles/donors/:id - Should display a specfic donor
```

routes in ruby on rails behave in the same way as href tag in rails

we use get for link and if we want toi perform any action on button then w e have to use button.

if you have any doubt let me know in detail.

for more details refer this

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

if we write only localhost:3000/employees then bydefault our application will redirect to index page.

Comment: add .html.erb as an extension to whatever file you specify.for eg: index.html.erb

Comment: Thanks for all your help guys. I think I found a route to solve the issue. I've just changed the type of file using notepad++ and renamed the file. You've resurrected my thirst to learn ruby.. Many thanks..

Answer (score 0):

The issue is template missing you are missing the template file index.html.erb

I have notice that on your snapshot you named the template file as index.html.erb.txt

remove the .txt and rename to index.html.erb Then it should work

Also you don't need to declare the routes as

`get 'posts/index' => 'posts#index'`

Just declare the `resources: posts` is enough. You may check the routes using the `rake routes` command on your rails console

Comment: I'm so glad I'm getting answers for this question. But when i initially created a file in my view folder -> posts, I've created a new text file and renamed it as index.html.erb However, when I try to edit this file with notepad++ or view the properties of the file it indicates it as index.html.erb.txt as it was initially created as a text file.

Comment: Thanks for all your help guys. I think I found a route to solve the issue. I've just changed the type of file using notepad++ and renamed the file. You've resurrected my thirst to learn ruby.. Many thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Rename the file `index.html.erb.txt` to `index.html.erb`